# Windows 7 x64 Hard Freezing (again)

Tags: windows-7, freeze, bsod

Awhile ago, my computer was randomly freezing a few minutes after booting, and I ended up replacing the CPU and mobo after testing the RAM and hard drive, I also couldn't find anything wrong with the video card.

So after replacing the presumably faulty hardware, everything worked fine for about a month and a half.  All of a sudden, My computer is randomly freezing a few minutes after loading up any intensive application (games, mostly).  Most of the time it just freezes with the current frame until I hard reset, although once it printed a BSOD message stating that dxgmms1.sys was to blame.

The only difference between these two episodes I can think of is that I can do word/internet/work without issue now, as opposed to the near uselessness my computer was rendered last time.

For those of you who want to know, I tested my memory with memtest86 (for 64 bit machines).
I can't figure out what could have started this latest round of issues, the event logger just states that a kernel-power event has occurred (like last time) but I think thats just a generic "this machine has rebooted after a sudden shutdown" message.

Answer (score 2):

Hopefully it's only a matter of overheating.  Clear out any dust, make sure the fans are operating efficiently (and not causing a dead-space, especially around the CPU), etc.

I've seen crashing computers like yours that were due to overheating, and on one I remember very clearly there were three chassis fans (including the power supply) all trying to push air outward.  After turning the front chassis fan around so that it pulls air in, the computer stopped crashing due to overheating.

Comment: +1 and check the fans to ensure they are well lubricated and not stuck. my bro's pc had a stuck fan and somehow that resistance caused energy disruption to the rest of the system. plugging out that fan restored stability.

Comment: You now, my fans might just all be pointing outward.  I'll have to check when I get back.  Though, any suggestions as to why it would've taken ~1 month for this to surface?

Comment: Please see this [Meta.SU question](http://meta.superuser.com/questions/2196/issues-with-openid-org-allow-users-register-with-their-email) about registering your account

Comment: Nope, I checked and my fans are all right.  I reseated the graphics card, which helped forawhile but then windows froze again...

Comment: @Lanissum:  Either your video card is overheating, or something is loose on the connector (to the motherboard and/or video card).  The intermittent nature of this particular problem generally points to the video card or its point of contact (which may include the motherboard), especially since re-seating it seemed to provide temporarily relief from the problem.